# Basic OpenPGM Setup

Tags: ip, virtualbox, multicast

I've recently begun to setup OpenPGM on a threesome of virtual linux machine with a fourth virtual machine acting as a gateway. Ideally I would like to observe the traffic using wireshark on the gateway. At this stage I'm only using the sample applications ( pgmrecv and pgmsend ) which operate as expected, but as soon as I set a static IP on a machine running pgmrecv, it errors and aborts iteself with the message:

> ** ERROR **: parsing network parameter: Unique address cannot be determined for interface 'eth0': Internet host resolution: Temporary
>   failure in name resolution(-3) aborting... Aborted

BTW, eth0' is the interface I am listening on, and there is no dhcp server involved in this network. Also, the gateway has port forwarding turned on.

I can ping between any of the machine in this virtual network with the static IPs.

Does anybody with experience with openPGM understand the cause of this error. How would assigning a static IP cause this?

I apologize if this is a rudimentary question; I am new to openPGM and could not find information on this issue posted elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I cannot explain the error message, I found that using the local IP address of the box as the argument passed with -n caused pgmsend and pgmrecv to function on a box with a static IP address.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved my issue. I was passing in "eth0". ugh....for some reason I became convinced that the issue had to do with my little virtual network.

Comment: Likely that "eth0" has both an IPv4 and IPv6 address as so OpenPGM does not know which address to use without further user input.

Answer (score 0):

If your eth0 ip address is 192.168.1.1 then you set openpgm reciever in this way:

```
sudo ./purinrecv -lp 7500 -n "192.168.1.1;239.192.1.1"
```

and sender in this way:

```
sudo ./purinsend -l -n "192.168.1.1;239.192.1.1" -p 7500 test_msg
```